# Gfi outlet trying to install light switch and light

Tags: electrical, switch, gfci

While trying to install light switch and light from an existing gfi outlet the circuit faults whenever switch is turned on also the light comes on in the off position 12 gauge 3 wire coming to building inside of gfi outlet there is a jumper (black)coming off the load side of gfi to a switch for 2 lights with a blue wire off of that switch and white also on load side of gfi  that is direct to lights   the blue and white are the ones being used to power the lights the black is jumpered also off of gfi load  side to another gfi outlet ,Lark is the buildings manufacturer

Comment: FYI Scott you can edit the question instead of commenting instead.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the wiring at the GFI, switch, and light? Or put them on Imgur and post a link to the pics?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you; please edit it into your question. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of the wiring in the various boxes involved?

Comment: Trying to upload pictures but keyboard no longer has icon?

Comment: The picture button is on the web page right above where you insert your text.

Comment: Says image to large? Thanks have tried to upload

Comment: @ScottBastian -- upload the pictures to [imgur](https://imgur.com) and post a link, then we can post them here

Answer (score 1):

### It's the LOAD terminals.

I know you've worked with regular outlets and are accustomed to seeing 2 screws on each side, and accustomed to using them as a convenient splice block.

So I gather you spotted some extra screws perhaps under some warning tape.  Those are the LOAD terminals, and those are *special* --  they are not to be used.

They have a special purpose that related to protecting *downline* locations - if you've ever seen a plain receptacle that somehow had GFCI protection anyway, it was protected by another GFCI.  If you want to do that, school up on use of LOAD - otherwise **stay away from LOAD**.

What's happening right now is your lamp has one wire on LINE and the other wire on LOAD, causing an inbalance that is tripping the GFCI.  Generally there's no reason to put a light on GFCI unless it's inside a shower.

You will need to either pigtail the LINE wires, or exploit the ["screw-and-clamp"](https://www.handymanhowto.com/electrical-outlets-side-wire-versus-back-wire/) feature of most GFCI receptacles that lets you put 2 wires on the "back wire" connectors under a screw.

Comment: They are on the load side of gfi?

Comment: So pigtail input is ok is what your saying and leave it completely off load side?

Comment: Yes, avoid LOAD.